# adding items to python dictionary by key

Tags: python, dictionary

The function below receives the following lists:

```
L1= [[12345,75,'English'],
         [23452,83,'Physics'],
         [23560,81,'Statistics'],
         [23415,61,'Computer'],
         [23459,90,'Physics'],    
         [12345,75,'Computer'],
         [23452,100,'Statistics']]

L2= [['a','English'],
           ['b','Physics'],
           ['c','Computer'],
           ['d','Statistics'],
           ['e','Philosophy']]
```

The function:

```
    def TeachMarks (L1, L2):
        teacherd=dict(L2)   #key- teacher name, value- subject
        Dc=dict.fromkeys(teacherd.values(),[]) #key-subj, value- empty list

        for i in L1:
           subj=i[2]
           Dc[subj].append(i[0])

         print '\n'
         print Dc
```

Each internal list in L1  has the subject in the [2] position.
Each key of the dictionary (Dc) is a subject and its value is an empty list.
The function is supposed to take the first element in the internal list and add it to the list which is the value of the relevant subject in the dictionary.

But when i run it, it actually adds the first element of each internal list (of L1) to each of the values. This is the output:

```
{'Statistics': [12345, 23452, 23560, 23415, 23459, 12345, 23452], 'Philosophy': [12345, 23452, 23560, 23415, 23459, 12345, 23452], 'Computer': [12345, 23452, 23560, 23415, 23459, 12345, 23452], 'Physics': [12345, 23452, 23560, 23415, 23459, 12345, 23452], 'English': [12345, 23452, 23560, 23415, 23459, 12345, 23452]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what do you want the output to be like?>

Comment: The default empty list is the same one for each key.

Comment: Are trying to check if `subj == i[2]`? Then make it an `if` and put `append()` inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.fromkeys` uses the *same* list for each key. You need separate lists; you should use a dict comprehension.

```
Dc={subject: [] for subject in teacherd.values()}
```

Comment: Can you explain what does it mean creates the same list (or refer me to a relevant explanation of fromkeys)? the first argument is a sequence of values (which in my case is the values from a different dictionary) and the second is what I want for values of the dictionary which is an empth list for each key)

Comment: A [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) might be a more convenient solution.

Comment: But it's not "an empty list for each key". It's *one* empty list, which is shared between all keys - hence the result you see.

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing the same empty list for each key.

You could use a [**`defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). This takes a factory function which is called for each new key. Pass it `list` and it will call `list()` to create missing keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def TeachMarks(L1):
    Dc = defaultdict(list)

    for value, _, subject in L1:
       Dc[subject].append(value)
```